# HP Color Laser Jet CP 1217 printer driver for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers

I'm a recent installer of Ubuntu 14.04 on a 64 bit computer, having binned Win 10, for it stole my nearly all drivers and won't let me have them back. Whilst I'm getting the hang of things I'm having big problems setting up my HP Color Laser Jet CP 1217 printer.

In the course of me trying,  I have found and downloaded the official set up program for it but can't locate any Ubuntu compatible drivers for the printer.

As I have two of these fantastic laser printers, one of which has had less than 60 sheets of paper through it from new, I'm loath to have to get rid of them and buy something new  that is Ubuntu ready.

I've spend a couple of weeks trying to get it up and running but seem to have spent most of it running round and round the same endless circle of nothing useful found.

I've joined several of these "We can get you any driver" sort of websites. They took my money but can't come up with the goods.

Can anyone give me a link for such an Ubuntu compatible driver for my printer or tell me the steps I have to walk to find out how to do it please?

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1):

According to this site, a plugin is required. http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/color_laserjet/hp_color_laserjet_cp1217.html Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui
```

Now, connect the printer and run:

```
hp-setup
```

It should find your printer and install the correct plugin and driver.

Comment: I've also found that if I'm trying to detect a wireless printer, I need to disable UFW while running hp-setup.